# How to truncate a stream when using a TextWriter

Tags: c#, .net, stream

this snippet should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
XDocument xd = ....
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
  using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
  {
    xd.Save(tw);
  }
  fs.Flush();
  fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
}
```

I want to serialize my `XDocument` to a stream using a `TextWriter` and then truncate the stream after the end of it. Unfortunately, the `Save()` operation seems to close the stream so my `Flush()` call generates an Exception.

In the real world, I'm not actually serializing to a file but some other kind of stream outside my control, so it's not a simple as just deleting the file first.

Comment: Andy keep in mind that when wrapping code around a `using` clause that once your process has left the `using( ) { }` block , objects are automatically disposed and underlying objects closed

Comment: Andy just curious can you show how / where you are using `XDocument xd = ....` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do this if you want to flush the stream

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
  using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
  {
    tw.Flush();
    xd.Save(tw);
    fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might need to call xd.Flush() just after the xd.Save() otherwise it might not have flushed its buffer to fs.

Comment: good catch I will update that my mistake when copying his code

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I think you meant `tw.Flush()`.

Comment: Thanks. I had already figured that I needed to move the SetLength inside the outer "using". I think I must have had a mental block not realising it had to be inside the inner one too :-)

Comment: That `tw.Flush()` should be *after* `xd.Save(tw)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853.aspx) of the StreamWriter constructor. Note the last parameter: You can tell it to leave the stream open.

Comment: Thanks for this - It's not the answer I was looking for but I didn't know about that overload and this is definitely something I will use in the future

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Save` closes the stream? The `TextWriter` is being closed at the end of the `using`. Perhaps this will work:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
  var TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs);
  try
  {
    xd.Save(tw);
    tw.Flush();
    fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
  }
  finally
  {
    tw.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Note that I flush the `TextWriter`, which also causes a flush of the underlying stream. Just flushing the `FileStream` might not include the data that's still buffered in the `TextWriter`.